# automatic node neighbor discovery in ns2 depending on transmission power

Tags: ns2

is there anyway where the nodes automatically calculates the neighbor nodes depending on transmission power in ns2 . I am using AODV routing protocol

Comment: i came across $node neighbors command in ns2 but i dont know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Do study WirelessChannel::sendUp() function in channel.cc
affectedNodes and getAffectedNodes would be parameters of your interest